# How to i get gaji from table gaji when i choose grade

Tags: php, laravel

**How to i get gaji from table gaji when i choose grade**

if I choose grade A, the salary will be 1000000 automatically

Pegawai.blade.php

@php

```
$A = DB::table('karyawan')->join('gaji','gaji.id', '=', 'karyawan.gaji_id')->->get('gaji.gaji');
$B = DB::table('karyawan')->join('gaji','gaji.id', '=', 'karyawan.gaji_id')->->get('gaji.gaji');
$C = DB::table('karyawan')->join('gaji','gaji.id', '=', 'karyawan.gaji_id')->->get('gaji.gaji');
$D = DB::table('karyawan')->join('gaji','gaji.id', '=', 'karyawan.gaji_id')->->get('gaji.gaji');

@endphp
                  <tbody>
                    @foreach($ar_karyawan as $peg)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $no++ }}</td>
                      <td>{{ $peg->nip }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $peg->nama }}</td>
                      <td>{{ $peg->gender }}</td>
                      <td>{{ $peg->tgl_lahir }}</td>
                      <td>{{ $peg->tgl_masuk }}</td>
                      <td>{{ $peg->grade }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
                  </tbody>
                </table>
```

PegawaiController.php

```
 public function index()
    {
         $ar_karyawan = DB::table('karyawan')
            ->join('gaji', 'gaji.id', '=', 'karyawan.gaji_id')
            ->select('karyawan.*', 'gaji.gaji AS gaji')
            ->get();
         return view('pegawai.index', compact('ar_karyawan'));

    }
```

table pegawai

https://i.imgur.com/Iy6ev8l.png

table gaji

https://i.imgur.com/MTxrJ0g.png

Comment: Before anything, make your mind up. Are you using laravel 5 or 6?

Comment: try different name like gaji_two in select option

Comment: i use laravel 6

Answer (score 0):

You wrote the code the wrong way. You wrote duplicate "->->"
Change the following code

from

```php
$A = DB::table('employee')->join('salary','salary.id', '=', 'employee.salary_id')->->get('salary.salary');
```

to

```php
$A = DB::table('employee')->join('salary','salary.id', '=', 'employee.salary_id')->get('salary.salary');
```